# passing video file through php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to pass a video file (webm) as a parameter through a php file so I can change the background when people watch the video. The problem I am having is when I try and access the video now it says "No video with supported format and MIMI type found". Any ideas?

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(webm))$ vid.php?vid=$1 [L]
```

And this is what I'm trying to pass it too.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['vid'])){ 
?>
<html>
<body style="background-color: white">
    <video controls loop style="width:100%">
        <source src="<?php echo $_GET['vid']; ?>" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're rewriting requests for `/example.webm` (for example) to `/vid.php?vid=example.webm`, then trying to include `example.webm` as a video within that page. However, that URL gets rewritten just like the original request did -- so the browser ends up with a mouth full of HTML instead of the WebM file it was expecting. There's no way to fetch the real video file.

You need to load the video from a different URL than the one that gets rewritten. This will probably mean putting it in a different directory.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking it was doing, just looping its self. When you say to load the video from a different directory, do you just mean a sub directory? Currently I have the webm in a folder called vids.